# How do I list all photos for my user account?

Tags: python, flickr

I'm trying to write a script that does the following:

- obtains a list of album (photoset) ID's from my flickr account
- list the image titles from each album (photoset) into a text file named as the album title

Here's what I have so far:

```
import flickrapi

from xml.etree import ElementTree

api_key = 'xxxx'
api_secret = 'xxxx'

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)

(token, frob) = flickr.get_token_part_one(perms='write')
if not token: raw_input("Press ENTER after you authorized this program")
flickr.get_token_part_two((token, frob))

sets = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id='xxxx')

for elm in sets.getchildren()[0]:
    title = elm.getchildren()[0].text
    print ("id: %s setname: %s photos: %s") %(elm.get('id'), title, elm.get('photos'))
```

The above simply outputs the result to the screen like this:

```
id: 12453463463252553 setname: 2006-08 photos: 371
id: 23523523523532523 setname: 2006-07 photos: 507
id: 53253253253255532 setname: 2006-06 photos: 20
... etc ...
```

From there, I've got the following which I assumed would list all the image titles in the above album:

```
import flickrapi

from xml.etree import ElementTree

api_key = 'xxxx'
api_secret = 'xxxx'

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)

(token, frob) = flickr.get_token_part_one(perms='write')
if not token: raw_input("Press ENTER after you authorized this program")
flickr.get_token_part_two((token, frob))

photos = flickr.photosets_getPhotos(photoset_id='12453463463252553')

for elm in photos.getchildren()[0]:
    title = elm.getchildren()[0].text
    print ("%s") %(elm.get('title'))
```

Unfortunately it just spits out a index out of range index error.

Comment: I see no difference between your 2 scripts besides the photoset_id, why would they output differently?

Comment: Confirm photos.getchildren() contains data before trying to iterate through it.  Also `for elm in photos.getchildren()[0]` looks to be the first array element - are you sure you don't mean `for elm in photos.getchildren():`?

Comment: @Fabricator ah yes - i see, i copied the same block of code twice. I've edited the original post to suit.

Comment: @LukePeterson thanks luke, i removed the [0] from the code and got this:
2013-05

I think it needs to go to the next level in the original XML. 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<rsp stat="ok">
  <photoset id="xxxx" primary="xxxx" owner="xxxx" ownername="xxxx" page="1" per_page="500" perpage="500" pages="9" total="4270" title="2009-12">
    <photo id="xxxx" secret="xxxx" server="xxxx" farm="x" title="2009-12-05 14-25-56" isprimary="1" />

I'm trying to get the title "2009-12-05 14-25-56", rather than the one above it.

thanks again.

Comment: @jztilly: Add that XML data into the question, where you can format it properly. Similarly, if you're getting an exception (such as an `IndexError`), please include the full traceback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I stuck with it and had a hand from a friend to come up with the following which works as planned:

```
import flickrapi
import os
from xml.etree import ElementTree

api_key = 'xxxx'
api_secret = 'xxxx'

flickr = flickrapi.FlickrAPI(api_key, api_secret)

(token, frob) = flickr.get_token_part_one(perms='write')
if not token: raw_input("Press ENTER after you authorized this program")
flickr.get_token_part_two((token, frob))


sets = flickr.photosets_getList(user_id='xxxx')

for set in sets.getchildren()[0]:
    title = set.getchildren()[0].text

    filename = "%s.txt" % (title)
    f = open(filename,'w')

    print ("Getting Photos from set: %s") % (title)

    for photo in flickr.walk_set(set.get('id')):
                f.write("%s" % (photo.get('title')))


    f.close()
```

Comment: Hm, how do you get the user_id though? Wait, I am looking for it :D

Answer (score 0):

Its quite easy if you use [`python-flickr-api`](http://code.google.com/p/python-flickr-api/). The complicated part is getting authorization from flickr to access private information.

Here is some (untested) code you can use:

```
import os

import flickr_api as flickr

# If all you want to do is get public information,
# then you need to set the api key and secret

flickr.set_keys(api_key='key', api_secret='sekret')

# If you want to fetch private/hidden information
# then in addition to the api key and secret,
# you also need to authorize your application.

# To do that, we request the authorization URL
# to get the value of `oauth_verifier`, which
# is what we need.

# This step is done only once, and we save
# the token. So naturally, we first check
# if the token exists or not:

if os.path.isfile('token.key'):
    flickr.set_auth_handler('token.key')
else:
    # This is the first time we are running,
    # so get the token and save it
    auth = flickr.auth.AuthHandler()
    url = auth.get_authorization_url('read')  # Get read permissions
    session_key = raw_input('''
                 Please visit {} and then copy the value of oauth_verifier:'''.format(url))

    if len(session_key.strip()):
        auth.set_verifier(session_key.strip())
        flickr.set_auth_handler(auth)

        # Save this token for next time
        auth.save('token.key')
    else:
        raise Exception("No authorization token provided, quitting.")

# If we reached this point, we are good to go!
# First thing we want to do is enable the cache, so
# we don't hit the API when not needed

flickr.enable_cache()

# Fetching a user, by their username

user = flickr.Person.findByUserName('username')

# Or, we don't know the username:

user = flickr.Person.findByEmail('some@user.com')

# Or, if we want to use the authenticated user

user = flickr.test.login()

# Next, fetch the photosets and their corresponding photos:

photo_sets = user.getPhotosets()
for pset in photo_sets:
    print("Getting pictures for {}".format(pset.title))
    photos = pset.getPhotos()
    for photo in photos:
        print('{}'.format(photo.info.title))

# Or, just get me _all_ the photos:

photos = user.getPhotos()

# If you haven't logged in,
# photos = user.getPublicPhotos()

for photo in photos:
    print('{}'.format(photo.info.title))
```

Comment: thanks for this but unfortunately doesn't get very far. i think the API hasn't been rewritten since flickr's move to HTTPS only connections.

Comment: Actually it was [updated for https](https://github.com/alexis-mignon/python-flickr-api/commit/135ead88196cd59c6c113d525d336e86b928cfd4) 3 months ago.